# Displaying column headers based on value their columns hold

Tags: excel

Using Excel 2013. I require a formula to check if a range of cells in columns are `0`, then the header should be displayed in a single cell. For example, for `Product 1` only B, C, D should be displayed, for `Product 2` E, F, H should be displayed, and in only a single cell:

```
Product    A    B   C   D   E   F   G   H
Product1        0   0   0                   
Product2                    0   0       0   
Product3            0   0   0   0
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If `Product` is in A1, please try in J2 and copied down to suit:

```
=IF(NOT(ISBLANK(B2)),B$1,"")&IF(NOT(ISBLANK(C2)),C$1,"")&IF(NOT(ISBLANK(D2)),D$1,"")&IF(NOT(ISBLANK(E2)),E$1,"")&IF(NOT(ISBLANK(F2)),F$1,"")&IF(NOT(ISBLANK(G2)),G$1,"")&IF(NOT(ISBLANK(H2)),H$1,"")&IF(NOT(ISBLANK(I2)),I$1,"")
```

A similar approach could be much shorter had the indictors been almost anything other than `0`.